# Angular 2 - Load route component and then gets back to previous component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have a problem with Angular 2 routing. When I click on my link to get the team details, it takes the right route and loads the component specified (TeamComponent). But, immediately "gets back" to the previous component (TeamsComponent), which is the teams list.

This is the structure of my project:

```
/app
|_shared
   |_team
      |_team.component.css
      |_team.component.html
      |_team.component.ts
      |_team.model.ts
      |_team.service.ts
   |_team-list
      |_team-list.component.css
      |_team-list.component.html
      |_team-list.component.ts
|_teams
   |_teams.component.css
   |_teams.component.html
   |_teams.component.ts
   |_teams.module.ts
   |_teams-routing.module.ts
```

First, I set the routes on *teams-routing.module.ts*:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TeamsComponent } from './teams.component';
import { TeamComponent } from '../shared/team/team.component';

const teamsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'team/:id',
    component: TeamComponent
  },{
    path: 'teams',
    component: TeamsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(teamsRoutes)
  ]
})
export class TeamsRoutingModule { }
```

Load the team list from the teamService on *teams.component.ts* and send it to team-list on *teams.component.html*:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';

import { TeamService } from '../shared/team/team.service';
import { Team } from '../shared/team/team.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teams',
  templateUrl: './teams.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teams.component.css']
})
export class TeamsComponent implements OnInit {

  teamList: Team[] = [];

  constructor(private teamService: TeamService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
      Observable.from(teams).subscribe(team => {
        this.teamList.push(team);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

*teams.component.html*

```
<section class="teams">
  <app-team-list [teams]="teamList"></app-team-list>
</section>
```

Then, with my teams list, I set the HTML list on *team-list.component.html*:

```
<section *ngFor="let team of teams" class="team_list">
  <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/assets/logos/{{team.logo}}" alt="Team Logo">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">{{team.name}}</h4>
      <p class="card-text">{{team.location}}</p>
      <a routerLink="/team/{{team.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Team Info</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Finally, I get the team info from param "id" and the service in *team.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Team } from './team.model';
import { TeamService } from "./team.service";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-team',
  templateUrl: './team.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team.component.css']
})
export class TeamComponent implements OnInit {

  team: Team = null;

  constructor(private teamService: TeamService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let teamId: number = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

    console.log("Vamos a buscar el equipo");
    this.teamService.getTeamById(teamId).subscribe(team => this.team = team);
  }
```

}

It loads the TeamComponent HTML with the team data, but gets back to /teams direction (and doesn't print the team list). I tried to change the routes names (/detail/:id for example) but still doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the route "teams" works the first time?

Comment: And how does your TeamService looks like?

Comment: Yeah @MarkusKollers, when I go to "/teams" for the first time, it prints the correct list.

Comment: I've build a clean angular-cli project and added your components and your service, and it works. Do you get any errors in your developer-console (F12)?

Comment: @MarkusKollers it says the property binding fields are null (ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TeamComponent.html:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:12822)). It's like the route /team/19 (for example) isn't working, and it's trying to render TeamComponent on /teams. In fact, at the Network section in Chrome debugger, /team/19 is never called. Very, very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it. Your request will be exuted async, so at the creation-time of your component, team is null. I think you have a binding like this in your TeamComponent:

```
{{ team.name }}
```

If team is null, name cannot be accessed and it crashes. To be sure the html will be rendered without errors, use the elvis-operator like this:

```
{{ team?.name }}
```

This will only access name if team is not null or undefined

Comment: That's it. What a beginner stupid mistake :( Thank you very much Markus. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The getTeamById service

```
getTeamById(id: number): Observable<Team> {

    let team: Team = null;

    return this.http.get(this.urlTeams+'/'+id)
      .map(response => {
        let dbTeam: any = response.json();
        for(let i in dbTeam) {
          team = new Team(dbTeam[i].teamId,dbTeam[i].teamName,dbTeam[i].teamLocation,dbTeam[i].teamFoundation,dbTeam[i].teamDivision,dbTeam[i].teamConference,dbTeam[i].teamStadium,dbTeam[i].teamAttendance,dbTeam[i].teamLogo,dbTeam[i].teamStadiumPhoto);
        }
        return team;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```